# Calling ClientID from aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net, clientid

"")" />

that doesn't work, the error says:
Parser Error Message: Server tags cannot contain <% ... %> constructs.

Any aproaches to solve this ? 
Thank you ;)

Comment: Why do you have runat="server" on a input? Shouldn't you use an asp-control?

Comment: it's because i needed to obtain the value from it in codebehing and the Asp:Checkbox was giving me conflicts with the updatepanel from ajax.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're calling a JS event (`onchange`), not a server event, so just pass in `this.id`.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chbSaveState" runat="server" tabindex="3"  
onchange="SaveState(this.id)" />
```

To be clear, `this.id` and `<%=chbSaveState.ClientID%>` will return the same value in this case. Since you're calling this on an event of `chbSaveState`, you can just use the easily accessible JS property here, rather than `<%=chbSaveState.ClientID%>`, which requires the server to return the id which is generated by the server for that control.

Answer (score 2):

you could do that using jQuery like this:

```
var control = '#<%= chbSAveState.ClientID%>';
$(control).change(function(){
    SaveState($(this).id);
});
```

Comment: Why bother with jQuery for something so straight-forward?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much experience with server side controls, but perhaps:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chbSaveState" runat="server" tabindex="3" 
onchange="SaveState(chbSaveState.ClientID)" />
```